# Binding textbox from Datagrid (WPF)

Tags: wpf

I am having trouble with XAML. I want to give my textbox a binding to my datagridview. This is what I've written so far:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtMaMH" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Height="23" 
          Margin="178,78,0,0" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         Text="{binding SelectedItem.MAMH, ElementName=dgvMH}" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Width="120"/>
```

But I received two errors:

> binding is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.
>
> The type 'binding' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

How to fix this? Please help me, thank you

And one more thing. I have a Datagridview (dgvMH) that has 2 columns MAMON, TENMON. I want to fill my textboxes txtMaMon, txtTenMon whenever I click on a row in that dgvMH. Is this the true XAML code? Correct me if I'm wrong, thanks

```
<TextBox x:name = "txtMaMon" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.MAMON, ElementName=dgvMH}"/>
<TextBox x:name = "txtTenMon" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.TENMON, ElementName=dgvMH}"/>
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvMH" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues I can see right off the bat.

1. When it says "binding" is not supporting in a WPF project, it's referring to the word you used in your XAML to try to bind your Text property. This is a typo - it should read `{Binding ... }`, not `{binding ... }`
2. Secondly, regarding MAMON and TENMON, your SelectedItem (presumably a DataGridCell or something of the like - that's a typo when you say "DataGridView," right?) doesn't have properties based on your columns, and even if it did, the selected cell isn't going to know about any column other than the one it's in. You can't access your columns by just adding .ColumnName after an item. (It's possible I'm misunderstanding something here - your variable names don't communicate much to me.)

If you're asking how to fill a TextBox with the currently-selected items, you should just bind to the SelectedItem property. Here's an example of how to to do that with a small test ViewModel:

Here's the DataGrid XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCells, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

And here's the TestViewModel and TestModel:

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new List<TestModel>() { new TestModel { CompanyName = "a", FirstName = "b", LastName = "c" }, new TestModel { CompanyName = "1", FirstName = "2", LastName = "3" } };
    }

    public List<TestModel> Items { get; set; }

    private TestModel selectedCells;
    public TestModel SelectedCells
    {
        get { return selectedCells; }
        set { 
            selectedCells = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCells");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class TestModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The TestViewModel's Items property provides the source for the items within the DataGrid. When one of these is selected, the change in the DataGrid's SelectedItem property is pushed to the property in the TestViewModel. If you wanted, you could bind the contents of your TextBox to SelectedItem as well, and create a converter to move between your model and your desired string representation. Alternately, and a little more simply, you could have a separate property (e.g. SelectedItemToText) which takes SelectedItem and stringifies it somehow within your ViewModel, though this is further from the MVVM pattern.

Comment: The first problem is solved, thank you, that's a typo mistake.
The second, it's Datagrid (Not Datagridview, cuz i'm mistaking WPF with WF sorry!)
I'll change the MAMON,TENMON to COURSEID,COURSENAME. Can u show me a wise code with SelectedItem Property please? I'm new to WPF :(

Comment: Okay, I can try, but I can't promise it'll work, given that I don't really have time to fully mock a DataGrid. Give me a second.

Comment: @NguyễnQuangKhải I've updated the answer with some code.

Comment: Thank you very much :)
Just few more minor questions if you don't mind.

First of all, Your public TestViewModel() must have a return type, is it int or what?

Secondly, Using your example, if I have 3 textboxes (txtCompanyName,txtFirstName,txtLastName), the XAML codes for these textboxes will be:

<TextBox x:name = "txtCompany" Text="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=dataGrid1}"/>
...

So how can these textboxes fill the right data for it? For example, the txtCompanyName will only fill the Company cell ('a' or '1') when I click a row in DataGrid

Comment: @NguyễnQuangKhải You misunderstand - a method with the same name as the enclosing class and no return type is a constructor. I'll look at your code in just a second.

Comment: Just tested your code, the Datagrid didn't show anything, maybe I should check again :P.
Anyway, thank to your codes, I somehow understand how the WPF binding works (although it still not clear).
One more time, Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @NguyễnQuangKhải Did you set the DataContext of the DataGrid to the TestViewModel? The DataContext property determines where the XAML looks for your bindings. So, if your DataContext was set to the TestViewModel, {Binding foo} would actually be TestViewModel.foo.

Comment: @NguyễnQuangKhải Also, given that this has been helpful, it'd be great if you could check the answer as your selected answer.

Comment: Ok, checked it :)). 
I just type the XAML codes and the code behind just like you, except the XAML of txtbox is mine. Still don't know why the itemssource Items couldn't send data to Datagrid :D